# $a \Rightarrow b$, $b \Rightarrow c$, $c \Rightarrow d$, $d \Rightarrow a$. Argue that any two of these statements are logically equivalent.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose a,b,c and d are statements such that $a \Rightarrow b$, $b \Rightarrow c$, $c \Rightarrow d$, $d \Rightarrow a$.  Argue that any two of these statements are logically equivalent.

Hey,  Im confused as to how to argue that this is true.  Is it similar to how you would prove a hypothetical syllogism?  Unfortunately this has me stumped and I can't even figure out how to start off.

Comment: I don't think that's right. For example, I don't see why the statement $a\implies b$ would be logically equivalent to the statement $c\implies d.$

Comment: Says "argue not prove.  I'd argue you get from any one statement to any other through a series of transitive implications.  Example: c=>a because c=> d which in turn=> a.

Comment: @bof 1) the statements are a,b,c,d not a=>b, etc.  2) a <=> c and b <=>d so (a => b) <=> (c => d)

Comment: @fleablood That apparently is the intent of the problem, but that's far from clear. I too,at first, interpreted the problem as bof did.

Comment: @fleablood 1) It would help if the OP would say what he means by "these statements". 2) Yes, if you **assume** that all four of the statements $a\implies b$ etc. are **true**, then they are all equivalent. On the other hand, if $a,b,c$ are true and $d$ is false, then the statement $a\implies b$ is true and and statement $c\implies d$ is false.

Comment: Apologies, the exact question is: Suppose a,b,c and d are statements such that $a \Rightarrow b$, $b \Rightarrow c$, $c \Rightarrow d$, $d \Rightarrow a$. Argue that any two of these statements are logically equivalent.  It says nothing else.

Comment: @sunsunsunsunsun The way to do this is to click "edit" and insert the missing information into the question itself (and maybe the title). Don't rely on people to read all the comments to know what the question is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write this chain two times: $a \Rightarrow b \Rightarrow c \Rightarrow d \Rightarrow a \Rightarrow b \Rightarrow c \Rightarrow d \Rightarrow a$
(this is true, it follows from what you have)

Now from here it's obvious that $x \Rightarrow y$  for any $x,y\in\{a,b,c,d\}$

Answer (score 2):

This is a circular graph with the statements $x_i$ as vertices and the implications $x_i \implies x_j$ as directed edges $(x_i, x_j)$.

This means you can reach any two statements $x$, $y$ via a finite number of implication, or $x \implies y$, because of the transitivity of the implication: If $x \implies y$ and  $y \implies z$, then $x \implies z$.

As $x \iff y$ means that the two implications $x \implies y$ and $y \implies x$ hold, every pair of statments $x$ and $y$ is equivalent, thus all are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Implication is a transitive relation. A transitive relation is a relation such that if $a \sim b$ and $b \sim c$, then $a \sim c$. So if $a \Rightarrow b$ and $b \Rightarrow c$ then $a \Rightarrow c$. Thus $a \Rightarrow c$ and $c \Rightarrow d$ imply that $a \Rightarrow d$ and $a \Rightarrow d$ and $d \Rightarrow a$ imply $a \Rightarrow a$.